# SPFX Source URL Redirect NOT Working

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, spfx

I am currently working on a custom WebPart in SPFX and am having some issues with a URL redirect.

The code is looking to see if a field is empty, if the field == empty then it will automatically redirect to the current page. If the field is NOT empty, the code will redirect to the URL provided in the field.

Here is the code:

```
var tableResults="";
      var response = request.currentTarget.response || request.target.responseText;
      var data = JSON.parse(response);
      var currentPageUrl = this.context.pageContext.site.serverRequestPath;
      var redirectURL = this.properties.redirect;
      if (data.error) {
          console.log(data.error.message.value);
      }
      else {
          tableResults="<table border='1' cellpadding='10' ><tr><th>Enroll</th><th>Event</th><th>Spots Left</th></tr>";
          for (var i=0; i<data.d.results.length; i++)
          {
              //alert(i + ": " + data.d.results[i].Time);
              if(parseInt(data.d.results[i].AttendeesId) < parseInt(data.d.results[i].Quota) && redirectURL == "")
              {
                tableResults=tableResults + "<tr><td><a href='https://ewscripps.sharepoint.com/sites/rsvp/Lists/Register/NewForm.aspx?SessionID="+ data.d.results[i].Id + "&Source=" + currentPageUrl + "'>Click To Enroll</a></td>";
              }
              else if (parseInt(data.d.results[i].AttendeesId) < parseInt(data.d.results[i].Quota) && redirectURL != "")
              {
                console.log(redirectURL);
                tableResults=tableResults + "<tr><td><a href='https://ewscripps.sharepoint.com/sites/rsvp/Lists/Register/NewForm.aspx?SessionID="+ data.d.results[i].Id + "&Source=" + redirectURL + "'>Click To Enroll</a></td>";
              }
              else
              {
                tableResults=tableResults + "<tr><td><font color='red'>Event Full</font></td>";
              }
              var spotsLeft = data.d.results[i].Quota - data.d.results[i].AttendeesId;
              tableResults=tableResults + "<td>" + data.d.results[i].Title + "</td><td>" + spotsLeft + "</td></tr>";
          }
          tableResults=tableResults + "</table>";

            //then you just need to generate the legend
            sessionsdiv.innerHTML= tableResults;
      }
```

The `console.log(redirectURL)` is showing the URL entered in the field, but for some reason, SharePoint is redirecting to the "All Items" list as it does by default.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a file called "Default.aspx" in that library

Comment: Check the redirectURL is "" or null.